# Importing ggplot to Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have installed ggplot and brewer2mpl successfully using the command:

```
   conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/bokeh ggplot
```

However when I try to import ggplot to Spyder with the command:

```
   from ggplot import *
```

I get the error message below:

```
   File "<ipython-input-107-02aeb6e281ab>", line 1, in <module>
from ggplot import *
   File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ggplot\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
from .scales.scale_color_brewer import scale_color_brewer
   File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ggplot\scales\scale_color_brewer.py", line 5, in <module>
   import brewer2mpl
   ImportError: No module named 'brewer2mpl'
```

Could you help me?  Thank you!

Comment: if you open python in a terminal do you get the same error?

Comment: No. After opening python in a terminal and typing "from ggplot import *" I get the error message: "ImportError: No module named 'ggplot'"

Comment: you likely have multiple instances then and only installed ggplot on one of them (not the default system one)

Comment: I had installed Python3.5 and then installed Anaconda. When I try to install ggplot by going to the Scripts subdirectory of the directory where Python 3.5 is installed and using pip3 I get error messages, e.g. "Failed building wheel for scipy" and many others. So I run the command "conda install ggplot" from the Anaconda Scripts subdirectory using the Windows commander. Then it seems that ggplot is installed without problems. The problem appears when I ask Spyder to import ggplot. What do I have to do to have ggplot run in Spyder?

Comment: I uninstalled Python 3.5 from my PC leaving only Anaconda and now ggplot is imported to Spyder without problems.